# How many spells does my level 1 druid know?

Tags: dnd-5e, spells, spellcasting, druid

I read the PBH (Players HandBook) but I'm confused; I know that it says that a level 1 druid has 2 spell slots but I didn't see how many spells a lv 1 druid knows. So far I put down 2 level 1 spells plus Cantrips but that doesn't look right to me, my druid should know more spells than 2 right? Her wisdom is 17 so her mod is +3 if that helps at all.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

From the Preparing and Casting Spells section of the Druid class:

> You prepare the list of druid spells that are available for you to cast, choosing from the druid spell list. When you do so, choose a number of druid spells equal to your Wisdom modifier + your Druid level (minimum of one spell). The spells must be of a level for which you have spell slots.

At level 1 with a +3 wisdom modifier, you may prepare 4 spells.
The 2 cantrips do not count against the 4 spells that may be prepared.

Comment: It should be said that your Druid knows ALL the druid spells they have spell slots for. The number of prepared spells is a subset of the spells known.